# JavaScript Date.parse doesn't accept Alaska Timezones?

Tags: javascript, timezone

JavaScript's Date.parse works fine with Pacific Time:

```
Date.parse('June 20 2015 10:22 PDT')
```

But it fails with Alaska Time

```
Date.parse('June 20 2015 10:22 AKDT')
```

Anyone know of a good solution to allow Alaska time?

Comment: Try UTC offsets. Like `UTC-05:00` or `UTC-0500`. That is the best solution. You can also use GMT offsets (simply replace UTC with GMT). In my opinion, that is the **OLNY** solution.

Comment: I have the date as a string with "AKDT" in it. I don't have the UTC offset.

Comment: `.replace('AKTD','UTC offset here')` should do it.

Comment: That's assuming I have the offset.

Comment: What the heck are you asking then? You ask why an `AKTD` timezone doesn't work. Maybe because it is 4-letters and not 3. Then you ask a solution: UTC offsets. Or I'm reading the question in a wrong way?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. You don't know the offset. According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Time_Zone) it is -08:00 hours.

Comment: It's fine that you don't know a solution. I'm looking for a solution. "PDT" is accepted just fine and AKDT isn't. Perhaps there's a library that includes more timezone strings than just PDT, EDT, and others.

Edit: absolutely ridiculous... I'm not trying to look up AKDT's timezone... I'm trying to use something like Date.parse with acceptance of more timezones, for example, AKDT.

Comment: Try moment.js. Also, I know the answer. But, based on what you have in your question, it is answered.

Comment: In the general case, you cannot parse time zone abbreviations.  There are too many ambiguities.  Consider that there are 5 interpretations of `CST`, 3 interpretations of `IST`, etc...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method accepts date strings formatted according to [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) or [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601).

RFC 2822, [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3), lists the parts of a valid date/time string.  The `zone` rule says the time zone designator should either be a UTC-style offset (e.g. -0800), or an `obs-zone` (obsolete) time zone designator.  [Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-4.3) lists the `obs-zone` designators, which include the familiar PDT, CST, etc., but not AKDT.

[ISO 8601 time zone designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) are limited to UTC only.

In short, you should either use UTC offsets in place of designators like AKDT, or write a mapping function to convert those [obsolete designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) to UTC before passing the datetime string to Date.parse().

EDIT:

This code's algorithm is inherently buggy.  As @MattJohnson notes in a comment to the original post, the obsolete time zone designators have several ambiguities - e.g. CST can map to 5 different UTC offsets.  Therefore, there's no general solution that can replace a time zone designator with a UTC offset and be confident that the correct replacement was made.

```
var timeZoneDesignatorMap = {
  akdt : '-0800',
  akst : '-0900',
  art : '-0300'
  
  // Add other designators here.
};

function mappedDateParse(dateString) {
  var name, newDateString, regex;
  
  for (name in timeZoneDesignatorMap) {
    regex = new RegExp(name, 'i');
    if (dateString.search(regex) !== -1) {
      newDateString = dateString.replace(regex, timeZoneDesignatorMap[name]);
      return Date.parse(newDateString);
    }
  }
  
  return Date.parse(dateString);
}

console.log(mappedDateParse('June 20 2015 10:22 AKDT'));
console.log(mappedDateParse('June 20 2015 10:22 -0800'));
console.log(mappedDateParse('June 20 2015 10:22 pDT'));
```

Comment: The O.P. complained about the suggestion to use UTC offsets, even though it is the only solution. Speaking about your code, I recommend that you move the map inside the function.

Comment: The issue is not using UTC offsets, the issue is not having access to them.

The proposed solution to use a map is reasonable, I just figured this issue had been tackled with some sort of plug-n-play library or jQuery function. If it is not, then I will be forced to write my own mapping.